# What are mitmproxy console navigation keys? Or controls, or key-bindings, or keyboard-shortcuts?

Tags: navigation, controls, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, mitmproxy

I'm running mitmproxy console.

I can navigate Flow view with *up/down arrow* keys and get from Flow view to request Flow Details view with *Enter* key or mouse click.

I can navigate Flow Details tabs Response/Request/Details with:
*Tab, arrow keys, h and l keys, Ctrl-I*.

I can change Flow Detail mode with m" key.

I don't understand what "z" and "v" key menu does. Same with "b" key.

I can get back to Flow view with "q" key.

**Is there any documentation on controls and navigation?**

Answer (score 7):

Use "?", which displays contextual help, depending on current view.